# how to post an image as a post, Kotlin + FireStore

Tags: kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I am making a small social network type app where the user enters text and images and then they are displayed on the main screen. I have already finished the part of the text but now I am missing the image. I have already made the function of opening the gallery for the user to select an image and reflect which one they have selected.

This is the function I use to open the device gallery and select one:

this is where the gallery opens

```
object imageController {
    fun selectPhotoFromGallery(activity: Activity, code: Int ) {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK)
        intent.type = "image/*"
        activity.startActivityForResult(intent, code)
    }
    fun saveImage(context: Context, id : Long, uri: Uri) {
        val file = File(context.filesDir, id.toString())

    val bytes = context.contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)?.readBytes()!!

    file.writeBytes(bytes)
  }
}
```

here is the image that the user selected:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    when {
        requestCode ==  SELECT_ACTIVITY && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK -> {
            imageUri = data!!.data

            imageView32.setImageURI(imageUri)
        }
    }
}
```

Now I just want the image to be saved in a document in firestore and finally show the image in the post.

For text in a firestore document it looks like this:

```
    holder.layout.name_service.text = post.service
```

How would it be to get an image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to do that. You should check out [Cloud Storage Save and Upload Images](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/start) . You can use that. It is designed for just that,storing media files. It is much more realiable.

You can jump to the section how to [upload files](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files)   here to get started. You will get more information.